# One card is dealt from a standard deck to each of seven players. What is the probability that the cards are in ascending order?

Tags: probability, permutations

This is from a textbook. The answer says it is about $4.1697 * 10^{-5}$.

This is in the permutations section of the text, so order matters (and from the way it is worded). Given that $P(A)=\frac{n(A)}{n(S)}$, then:
$n(s)=\frac{52!}{(52-7)!}$ --> the number of ways that 7 cards can be given from a deck of 52, where order matters.
n(A)=1 (it seems to me) since, given any set of seven cards, there is only one way that they can be in ascending order.
Thus, by my calculation, $P(A)=1.48*10^{-12}$.
But, I do not get the answer that is in the back of the book. Am I wrong, or is the text?

Comment: Doesn't your answer assume that no cards are equal in the order? Which is first, the seven of diamonds or the seven of hearts? (And then the question becomes, does the question mean strictly increasing?)

Comment: (And my reading of the question with increasing meaning "increasing strictly by rank" gives the result $4.1697\times 10^{-5}.$

Answer (score 3):

In a standard deck, the rank of a card is one of $13$ values, and there are four cards of each rank.

In that case, the number of ways to pick $7$ cards of (strictly) increasing rank is $n(A)=\binom{13}{7}4^7.$

This number gives the result you've been given, $0.000041697.$

---

Even given your reading - essentially that there are $52$ cards labeled from $1$ to $52$ - the answer should be:

$$\dfrac{\binom{52}{7}}{{}_{52}P_{7}}=\frac{1}{7!}$$

There are $n(A)=\binom{52}{7}$ ordered set of seven cards, not $n(A)=1.$

Comment: I am teaching a section in the text which has not yet taught combinations. So, we can only use permutation notation. Is there a way that this can be done without using combinations?